# AJAX Jsonp call fails in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have following code

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.jsp',
                data: 'id=111',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success:  function(data) {
            alert(data.result);
                },
                error: function( err1, err2, err3 )
        {
              alert('Error:' + err3 )
        }
            });
```

I am returning response as callback parameter generated with argument of json . like this

```
jQuery16105097715278461496_1314674056493({"result" : "success"})
```

This works absolutely fine in FF . In IE 9 it goes to error function and shows

```
"Error: jQuery16105097715278461496_1314674056493 was not called" .
```

when I see F12 . I see a warning which says .

```
SEC7112: Script from http://otherdomain.com
index.jsp?callback=jQuery16105097715278461496_1314674056493
&eid=111&_=1314674056493 
was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/27/ie9-beta-google-image-search-javascript-content-type-and-nosniff.aspx

Comment: What exactly is being returned from the server? If IE debug tools don't show it, you could use a tool called Fiddler to sniff the communications out.

Comment: @zzzz I added also response request headers I will appreciate it if you can tell me where exactly I have issue .

Comment: @Chris Pietschmann  i added request and response images here.

Comment: @sonesh can we test it somewhere? host it on jsfiddle? any reason for making it a post?

Comment: i'm having exactly the same problem. is this a new thing? it used to work fine...

Comment: @json Not sure whats causing this in IE . Its really hectic to spend extra time for everything to make it work in IE

Comment: @sonesh see my answer.. this isn't IE's fault, it's twitter's...

Comment: Hmm.... In my case its a cross site ajax call and I am not calling any thing related to twitter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a contentType

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'index.jsp',
     data: {id:'111'},
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success:  function(data) {
       alert(data.result);
     },
     error: function( err1, err2, err3 )
     {
       alert('Error:' + err3.status );
       alert(err1.responseText);
        }
 });
```

here is a good article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Tried that it didnt make any difference.

Comment: try `application/javascript` instead of `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

**This library is heavenly helpful I found it after wasting a lot hours.**

Use this library https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest then you won't need to use jsonp.

And your Cross Site request will begin to work normally.